# How to comment out a code on VS code terraform

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform, comments

I wish to find out how to comment out a code on VS code in Terraform. I am new to the world of coding, and Amazon web services. I am still learning to use terraform.

Answer (score 15):

[Attaching the Terraform documentation for commenting](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/configuration#comments:%7E:text=character%20%2D.-,Comments,-The%20Terraform%20language)

The Terraform language supports three different syntaxes for comments:

`#` begins a single-line comment, ending at the end of the line.

`//` also begins a single-line comment, as an alternative to `#`.

`/*` and `*/` are start and end delimiters for a comment that might span over multiple lines.

The `#` single-line comment style is the default comment style and should be used in most cases. Automatic configuration formatting tools may automatically transform `//` comments into `#` comments, since the double-slash style is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to comment out code in Terraform is to add a hash at the start of the lines:

```
variable "var_1" {
  type    = string
  default = "value-1"
}

# variable "var_2" {
#   type    = string
#   default = "value-2"
# }
```

In the above example, Terraform will create the variable called `var_1`, but will not create the variable called `var_2` because that variable has been commented out.

You can check out the [Terraform Configuration Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/language/syntax/configuration#comments).